# Installed the Package but it is not working

Tags: python

I have installed  all the packages related to multiprocessing and Pool in pycharm IDE but cant solve the problem saying that No module named 'multiprocessing.pool'.

Comment: ```from multiprocessing import pool```

Comment: Hi @ali .
Did you have a moment to read my answer? 
If you found it useful please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer for your question.
Thanks!

Comment: I have already added " from  multiprocessing import pool"  package. I can see it has been added  to my environment IDE.

Comment: but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Please add at top of your script:

```
from multiprocessing import pool
```

**Explanation**

If you don't import the modules you are using in your Python script you will get similar errors.

Here's a small example of the same concept but using the random module instead of multiprocessing:

```
import random


for i in range(10):
    print(random.randint(1, 25))
```

If you remove or comment the "import random" line and run the code you will get, again, a No module named 'random' error.

Here's also Python official documentation about the topic:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Hi @Ali, if my answer was useful for you please consider upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings in Pycharm. If you want to install the packages manually go into file, settings and Environment. Use the + sign on the right hand side of the screen. Search for the package you have downloaded/installed using the search bar. Once located click on the packages you want to install to the environment and click install package. You should then see it added to your environment and it will find the module.